# JSTree showing duplicate nodes

Tags: php, jquery, recursion, jstree

I recently started using JSTREE to display my json data (I am showing it as an array in my sample code here). But, some of the nodes are repeating. I was thinking of adding an If loop to check if the node is already a child node but not sure how to do that. I also think my code is also not very well performing because of the many for loops. I am a PHP newbie so not sure if there might be a faster way to recurse through an array. Here is my code.

```
$relation = array(

        "parent"=>array("item"=>array("cs","ls")),

        "cs"=>array("item"=>array("cs_1")),

        "ls"=>array("item"=>array("ls_1")),

        "cs_1"=>array("item"=>array("cs_1_1"))

        );

    $tree = array();

    $i=0;

    foreach($relation as $key_parent=>$value_parent) {

        #$children = array_keys($value_parent);

        $tree[$i++] = array('id'=>$key_parent,'text'=>$key_parent,'state'=>array('opened'=>true),'parent'=>'#');    

        foreach($value_parent['item'] as $key_child_1=>$value_child_1) {

            $tree[$i++]= array('id'=>$value_child_1,'text'=>$value_child_1,'state'=>array('opened'=>true),'parent'=>$key_parent);   

        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your input structure is far from optimal, but it can still work. If I understand correctly, this is what you need:

```
$relation = array(
    "parent"=>array("item"=>array("cs","ls")),
    "cs"=>array("item"=>array("cs_1")),
    "ls"=>array("item"=>array("ls_1")),
    "cs_1"=>array("item"=>array("cs_1_1"))
);

$tree = array();

foreach($relation as $key_parent=>$value_parent) {
    $tree[$key_parent] = array('id'=>$key_parent,'text'=>$key_parent,'state'=>array('opened'=>true),'parent'=>'#');    
    foreach($value_parent['item'] as $key_child_1=>$value_child_1) {
        $tree[$value_child_1]= array('id'=>$value_child_1,'text'=>$value_child_1,'state'=>array('opened'=>true),'parent'=>$key_parent);   
    }
}

$tree = array_values($tree);
```

The only fix is using the actual node ID as a key in the `$tree` array, and then calling `array_values` to convert it back.